# Ruby on Rails/HTML - Inline forms :checked => false is not working

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

**What I want:**
I want the default option for this form to be "No" (or false), and yet when I set it as the above, my app loads with no option chosen.

When I do `:check => true`, the default option selected is "Yes" (or true), so I figured switching to false and move it to the No option would work, yet it doesn't.

Relevant code:

```
      <div class="form-group">
            <%= label(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'Can be Shipped?')%>
            <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="radio inline">
                <%= radio_button(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, true)%>
                <%= label(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'Yes', :value => true)%>
            </div>
            <div class="radio inline">
                <%= radio_button(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, false)%>
                <%= label(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'No', :value => false, :checked => false)%>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div
```

What should I be doing here so the default option checked is "No" (false)?

Thank you.

Comment: `<label>`s don't have `value` or `checked` attributes, they have `for` attributes which reference the radio button which does have those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `:checked => true` in your 'No' label?

```
<%= label(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'No', :value => false, :checked => true)%>
```

Comment: Hi Gabriel, thanks for your comment. I've just done that now, and annoyingly it still doesn't work.

Comment: I guess that your object is returning the first radio button value (third parameter, true), and because of that it always returns checked.
Example: `store_item.can_be_shipped` returns `true` and it always checks the radio button that matches. In your case the first one.

Here is the code where radio_button is implemented inside rails, maybe this documentation can help you:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1304

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are set `:checked => true` in your label, but you need set this attribute on your `radio_button`.

If you want the default option for this form to be "No" the correct code it would be:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'Can be Shipped?')%>
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="radio inline">
        <%= radio_button(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, true)%>
        <%= label(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'Yes', :value => true)%>
      </div>
      <div class="radio inline">
        <%= radio_button(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, false, :checked => true)%>
        <%= label(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'No', :value => false)%>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This generate a form with "No" as default checked option:

[image]

You can see a [example of input type checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_checkbox) with `checked` html5 attribute on w3schools.